# Can we say that: $\|g\|_\infty<M $?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite measure space and  $\{f_n\}\subset \mathcal{L}^2$, such that:
$$
\forall n\geq 1~:~|f_n|\leq M~~a.e\qquad (1)
$$
and
$$
\exists g\in\mathcal{L}^1, \text{such that } f_n\underset{n}{\to}g\text{ weakly in }{L}^2\qquad (2)
$$
Can we say that:
$$
|g|\leq M~~a.e
$$

Comment: Is $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ the [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum)?

Comment: @RhysSteele see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes we can. By contradiction, assume that $\mu\left(g > M\right) >0$. Since $f_n \to g$ weakly in $L^2$, we have
$$M \mu(g>M) < \int g \mathbf{1}_{g >M} \, d \mu = \lim_n \int f_n \mathbf{1}_{g>M} \, d \mu \leq M \mu(g>M).
$$
Thus, $\mu(g>M) = 0$. Applying this to $-g$, we get that $\mu(|g|>M) = 0$, i.e. $|g| \leq M$ a.e.